# Cancel fade out of audio then fade in - Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to start fading out, but then be able to cancel that and fade in from the current volume level.

First I tried this:

```
gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, audioCtx.currentTime + 5);
setTimeout(function(){
    gainNode.gain.cancelScheduledValues(audioCtx.currentTime);
    gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, audioCtx.currentTime + 5);
}, 3000);
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cnt52fm/21/))

This didn't work in either Firefox or Chrome. The fade out starts, then when the timeout function fires, the gain value just jumps back to 1.

Then I found that this one works in Chrome:

```
gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, audioCtx.currentTime + 5);
setTimeout(function(){
  const val = gainNode.gain.value;
  gainNode.gain.cancelScheduledValues(audioCtx.currentTime);
  gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(val, audioCtx.currentTime);
  gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, audioCtx.currentTime + 5);
}, 3000);
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cnt52fm/19/))

...But not in Firefox, as it returns the last set value of the gain instead of a computed one, which is 1, so it transitions from 1 to 1, so the result is the same as in my first try.

So these left me with the questions...

- Is my last solution spec compatible or just a Chrome bug?
- Is there a cross-browser (at least Firefox + Chrome) solution to the problem?
- Is there a cross-browser solution to the problem which is spec compatible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want "cancelAndHoldAtTime()" (https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-cancelandholdattime).  Unfortunately, not yet implemented in Firefox.